# High Order Functions in Java

Tags: java, function

I was wondering if there is a way to pass a function as an argument to a method. Is there anyway I can do this in Java 8? Please thoroughly explain the steps I must take in order to do so, and thank you in advance.

Comment: IMO this would be a better question if you gave an actual or hypothetical example. Otherwise it's a pretty broad question based on situations. The best thing to do is look at the Javadocs without a specific problem trying to do so.

Comment: I am making a library and I want to allow users to pass error callbacks.

Comment: @makoto The linked question doesn't show to to define a method that receives a function. You shouldn't close this so promptly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. Look at the [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package for the different types of functional interfaces you can use.

What you might want is `Function<T, R>` which is a signature for a function that takes in a single argument of type `T` and returns a value of type `R`. There are other interfaces for more-specific cases. For example, let's say you wanted a predicate of some kind. Then you can use `Predicate<T>` to describe that you want to accept a method that returns a boolean value based on some interpretation of the value of type `T`.

This is how a lot of the methods work on streams. For example, the [`forEach`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) in `Stream<T>` is a method that accepts an argument of type `Consumer<? super T>`. This is basically a function that takes in an argument and does something with it.

As far as passing in the functions themselves, you can use [method references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) or create an ad-hoc implementation of a functional interface through lambdas.

Here's a contrived example where I'm iterating over a map and adding all the values to a list:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Integer> map = fromSomeMethod();

map.values().stream().forEach(list::add);
```

Here `forEach` accepts a consumer function of type `Consumer<? super T>`, which in this case is the `add` method from `Collection<E>` (which `List<T>` implements). Therefore, you've basically passed in a method as an argument into another method.

Here's another example where I'm using the same method, but this time I'm printing out the elements of a list:

```
list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Using this you can create your *own* methods that accept other methods, and it is as simple as defining an argument that is of any one of the types defined in `java.util.function`. For your error callback case, you could do something like this:

```
public void doSomething(String something, Consumer<ErrorResult> errorHandler) {

    //do some stuff
    if(errorHappened) {
        //call the error handler with a new ErrorResult object
        errorHandler.accept(new ErrorResult(...)); 
    }
}
```

Then let's say you have a method that simply prints out the error result in some class

```
public class ConsoleErrorHandler {
    public void handleError(ErrorResult result) {
        System.out.println(result.getErrorMessage());
    }
}
```

Now you can invoke `doSomething` with a reference to `handleError` from an instance of `ConsoleErrorHandler`:

```
ConsoleErrorHandler handler = new ConsoleErrorHandler();
doSomething("Something", handler::handleError);
```

You could even do this ad-hoc, with a lambda:

```
doSomething("Something", (ErrorResult result) -> {
    System.out.println(result.getErrorMessage()); 
});
```

Notice that because of generics, you get compile-time type-checking so that you cannot simply pass *any* method that accepts a single argument into `doSomething`.

Comment: @VivinPaliath, I downvoted it when it was a link-only, then you deleted it, or it appeared, and now I've taken it back and gave one too.

Answer (score 5):

There's not function types in Java, so you have to use single method interfaces.

The package [java.util.function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) defines a lot of them, but any interface with a single method can be used.

For instance:

```
// An interface with a single method that return 
// something of type T
interface F<T> {
    T doSomething();
}
class A {
    // This method expect an instance of the interface F
    private static String f( F<String> x ) {
        // and then invokes its only method.
        return x.doSomething();
    }

     // Test it
    public static void main( String ... args ) {
        //Call the method f using a 
        // this function literal: ()-> "hola"
        System.out.println(
            f( () -> "hola" )
        );
    }
}
```

The function literal:

```
() -> "hola"
```

Satisfies the interface `F<T>` implicitly.

In summary, you specify the type as an interface with a single method (any interface). It's even better if you use one of the existing interfaces in the java.util.function package.

I hope this helps.